# htaccess seo url friendly with \ and /

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, seo

I have search of tires in my web, and I have 3 parameters to search: width, slice, and koter(radius)

I want the to direct after the search to this url:
example.com/tires/width/sliceR/koter - > example.com/tires/205/55R/16

the values that I get from the user are only numbers, like:
width: 205
slice: 55
koter(radius): 16

And I writing this code:

```
RewriteRule ^tires/$ /tires.php [L]
RewriteRule ^tires/([0-9/]+)/([^/]+)/([0-9/]+)$ /tires.php?width=$1&slice=$2&koter=$3 [L]


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^width=(\w+)&slice=(\w+)&koter=(\w*)$
RewriteRule ^ http://example/tires/%1\/%2\/%3? [R,L]
```

but it's didn't work... and I have problem with the / in the last url:
http://example.com/tires/15/15R/15/ - is work
http://example.com/tires/15/15R/15 - isn't work

and also, I have problem with double number:
example.com/tires.php?width=205&slice=55&koter=17.5 didn't redirect to url friendly.

thank you and sorry for my ignorance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+tires\.php\?width=([^\s&]+)&slice=([^\s&]+)&koter=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ tires/%1/%2/%3? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^tires/$ tires.php [L]
RewriteRule ^tires/([0-9.]+)/([^/]+)/([0-9.]+)/?$ tires.php?width=$1&slice=$2&koter=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Good that you use 302, +1. And I believe you meant `[0-9.]+` at $3 as well. Radius could also be a float.